# Azure Website Node.JS doesn't run 64 bit.

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

After a recent Azure Website update, it has broken some of our websites that run on Node.JS. After running some tests to see what kind of architecture the website is running on, it turned out to be running on IA64. And thats while the config is chosen as 32 bit, instead of 64 bit. 
It would be fine, if changing it to 64 bit would also change the NodeJS to 64bit as well, but that stays in a 32bit format.

So my question is this: how can i ensure that both the OS and the NodeJS runtime runs on the same architecture. Either 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 3):

azure websites by default does not have 64bit node.exe installed. The workaround for what you want to do would be place both 32 bit and 64 bit node.exe in d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\x86 and d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\amd64 respectively and then in your web.config configure nodeProcessCommandLine="d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\node.exe" as shown below:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
  </handlers>
    <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%\node.exe"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

here, the env variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE reflects the bitness of the worker process. Please let me know if this does not work.

d:\home\site\wwwroot is your azure website's wwwroot folder.